Does LQG break gauge invariance?
So, I'm working with another researcher on a possible connection between Loop Quantum Gravity (LQG) and String Theory (ST). My colleague is proposing and insisting on a action that is not WS reparameterization invariant, I said that is problematic and there is a (very) easy fix, but he insists that it is fine since, in his words, "a discrete geometry is expected to break gauge invariance". I couldn't find any information agreeing with his statement, on the contrary I found lots of papers showing LQG preserving gauge invariance and he refuses to elaborate further his point. Can any one experienced in LQG confirm that yes, indeed LQG quantum geometry is expected to violate gauge invariance, or is he saying non-sense?

What does worldsheet parameterization invariance mean in LQG? It doesn't have worldsheets

We are modeling a string propagating in an LQG background, so the worldsheet comes from this string. More specifically, we imagine the string as emerging from a violation of Gauss law on a sequence of edges of the spin network, then it's propagation through the spin foam gives the WS
